# Keycloak angular app file uploading not sending token

Tags: angularjs, keycloak

This is my angular configuration for appending keycloak token with every HTTP request.

```
module.factory('authInterceptor', function($q, Auth) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (Auth.authz.token) {
                Auth.authz.updateToken(5).success(function() {
                    config.headers = config.headers || {};
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + Auth.authz.token;
                    deferred.resolve(config);
                }).error(function() {
                        deferred.reject('Failed to refresh token');
                    });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
module.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider)  {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
}]);
```

This is the request I sending to the backend. It seems the request not adding keycloak token, so I'm getting 403 forbidden error.

```
var formData = new FormData(file);
formData.append('file', file);
return $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: API_BASE + '/uploadEmployeeDetails/excelUpload',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': undefined
  },
  data: formData,
  transformRequest: function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
    return data;
  }
});
```

**Backend security config**[image]

Comment: When I change the POST method to GET on both backend and frontend will solve the 403 forbidden issue. So why POST method producing forbidden error?

Comment: How is your backend protected ?

Comment: The backend is Bearer only protected.

Comment: Only POST method is showing 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Okay, Can you share the backend code and configuration ?

Comment: Please check the updated question.

Comment: Please give me your mail ID i will share the code.

Comment: check is token is being sent via the headers or not form the browser

Comment: @Sravan How do i check that?

Comment: Open browser console, and go to network tab, now make the post request, you can check the request headers when you click on the request that was displayed in network tab of browser

Comment: Yes the token is sent via Request Header

Comment: so the token is being sent to server also check if any extra space is added in the token..  check from where the error is coming from api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146026/discussion-between-boycod3-and-sravan).

Comment: @SébastienBlanc  Response Tab in browser console showing this..{"timestamp":1496818525385,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?","path":"/personalDetail/printName"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are able to send the `token` to the back-end as you can see from the network tab of the browser.

The issue is in the `api` side on handling the `csrf token`

If the `csrf token` is enabled by default you should disable it.

Here is the code with your help, to disable it

```
http.csrf().disable(); 
http.addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class) 
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**") 
.hasAnyRole("ORG_ADMIN", "EMPLOYEE", "PARENT", "STUDENT") 
.anyRequest().permitAll();
```